# Use computed property in data in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I use a computed property in the data or emit it via bus?

I have the following vue instance, but myComputed is always undefined but computedData is working correctly.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data(){
    return{
      myComputed: this.computedData
    }
  },

  computed: {
    computedData(){
      return 'Hello World'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Why do you need this? You can always just access `this.computedData` the same way you would access `this.myComputed`

Comment: It's not working with this. computedData, it's undefined.

Comment: What I mean is you can access computed properties the exact same way you access data so there is not need to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: So I'm trying to emit the computed property and that wasn't working like so `bus.$emit('send-computed-data', this.computedData);` any ideas then?

Comment: Sounds like your this isn't the component from the calling context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to emit from mounted in Vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318643/is-it-possible-to-emit-from-mounted-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 36):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to use computed property in data because of component creation timing: data evaluates Before computed properties.

Answer (score 11):

To make things as simple as possible, just do the work in watcher, unless you want to emit the changes to different components or there're a lot of variables you want to notify, then you may have to use Vuex or the event bus:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data(){
    return{
      myComputed: '',
      computedData: 'Hello World'
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.myComputed = this.computedData;
  },
  watch: {
    computedData() {
      this.myComputed = this.computedData;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You can now do even...
`watch: {
       computedData: {
           handler: val => this.myComputed = val,
           immediate: true,
       }
    }`
And skip the duplicate `created` part altogether... See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Answer (score 4):

1. Computed is already accessible in the template using {{ }}.
2. But you can use the

```
watch:{
  //your function here
}
```

instead of computed

Answer (score 3):

you can work just with the computed function

```
   var vm = new Vue({
      data(){
        return{
          //is not necessary
        }
      },
    
      computed: {
        computedData(){
          return 'Hello World'
        }
      }
    })
```

and in your template

```
<template>
  <div>{{ computedData }}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using computed/reactive objects then it should be inside the `computed` and not inside the `data`.

Simply change your code to use computed instead of data

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data(){
    return{}
  },

  computed: {
    computedData(){
      return 'Hello World'
    },
    myComputed(){
     return this.computedData
    }
  }
})
```

you are trying to use `data` as `computed` and this shall not be.
data doesn't act like computed object.

and it's not because of component creation timing. What if we changed the component creation timing ? this will not solve anything as data will take only the first computed value(only one) and will not update after.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-coding it. Computed props are accessible in the same manner as data props in your template.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  computed: {
    myComputed(){
      return 'Hello World'
    }
  }
})
```

In the template you have access to this just like you do to data:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ myComputed }}</div>
</template>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 0):

**`computed` is not available at the time `data` gets initialized.**

If it should be a one-time thing (and NOT reactive), you could achieve this by setting the data at the moment where the computed property is available by using the `created()` hook:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    myDataBackend: '',
  }),
  computed: {
    computedData () {
      return 'Hello World'
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$set(this, 'myDataBackend', this.computedData)
  }
}
```

Futher reading: [Vue Documentation on Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

---

**In case you are trying to work with `v-model`:**

You could also use `:value` and some event like `@change` or `@keyup` in the element instead.

- `:value` is the value which the input-element initially works with
- After writing some letter in the input field, the `@keyup` event changes the data.
  Typically, events carry the updated form value in `target.value`
- The `changeMyData` method sets the value
- the computed property listens to the data change and the `:value` of the input field gets updated.

*Note:* I used `data` as a data store. But you could also use for example vuex instead.

```js
<template>
<div>
  <input
    type="text"
    :value="computedData"
    @keyup="changeMyData"
  />
  <p>{{myDataBackend}}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    myDataBackend: 'Hello World'
  }),
  methods: {
    changeMyData(evt) {
        this.$set(this, 'myDataBackend', evt.target.value)
        console.log('Changed the value to: ' + evt.target.value)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedData () {
      return this.myDataBackend
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the computed in a method

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data(){
    return{
      myComputed: this.computedData
    }
  },

  methods: {
    computedData(){
      return 'Hello World'
    }
  }
})
```

This is simple and it works (NOT reactive), but has a cost:

https://medium.com/notonlycss/the-difference-between-computed-and-methods-in-vue-js-9cb05c59ed98

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now you can use `computed` *(composition api feature)* in `data` by using **computed** function from vue. Here is an example.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ person.info }}</div>
    <div><button @click="changePersonId">change id</button></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      person: {
        name: 'Evgeny',
        id: this.generateId(),
        info: computed(() => `${this.person.name} with id = ${this.person.id}`)
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    generateId() {
      return +`${Math.random()}`.slice(2);
    },

    changePersonId() {
      this.person.id = this.generateId();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It works absolutely as normal computed property. You can assign getters and setters as well:

```js
info: computed({
  // arrow functions syntax must be for right this value
  get: () => {
    return `${this.person.name} with id = ${this.person.id}`
  },
  set: (value) => {
    this.person.name = value
  }
})
```

Imho, it is good an opportunity to group properties together and share it among child components without repeating computed properties there and to add some common computed props just as object property.

It is very useful, that we can use some vue 3 features in vue 2!

[Read abount vue3 computed props](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html)