# Is it possible to emit from mounted in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am familiar with emitting data via bus on events and these work great but now I want to emit something but I don't have an event to tie it to.

I've tried to emit it on mounted but that hasn't worked as below:

```js
mounted(){
  bus.$emit('send-test', this.test);
},
```

Comment: How is it not working? This should work fine.

Comment: I suspect you can't emit on mounted because you need an event? it works fine if I attach it to an event in watch.

Comment: You can emit on mounted. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/eROrWM?editors=1010

Comment: That is odd. The data I need to emit is actually from a computed property. Could it be that isn't available at mounted?

Comment: Computed values are available in mounted. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/eROrWM?editors=1010

Comment: This is very odd, it seems that in this instance I am unable to emit from mounted. Do you have any clue what could cause that?

Comment: Not really, without the code.

Comment: I think you'll see what I'm taking about here, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRbMjW?editors=1010 I used your example as a template. You should see 'hello world' on the page but it is not showing.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, where the `$on` is added in the `mounted` it's added *after* the $emit has already occurred. Children mount before the parent.  The $emit happens just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you add an event handler in the *parent's* `mounted` lifecycle event for an event that is emitted in a *child's* `mounted` event, the handler will not catch the event emitted by the child because the handler is added *after* the child has already emitted the event. Basically the cycle of events is like this.

1. Parent's create
2. Child's create
3. Child's mounted
4. Parent's mounted

Obviously there are other lifecycle events that occur, but that's the sequence that matters in this case.

If you want to handle an event emitted in the child, you need to create the handler (call $on) *before* the child's `mounted` event.

Comment: @Bert would be you provide an example (to your last point)? I'm don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @phil Essentially it's the point of the answer; the original question was why the parent doesn't catch the event emitted by the child when the parent was adding the handler to catch the event in the parent's mounted lifecycle handler. That point is *too late*. If you want to catch events emitted in the child's create or mounted lifecycle, you *must* add the handler in the parent's create lifecycle event.

Comment: You can meanwhile use `@hook:mounted` on the children, to know when it is actually mounted. As explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080141/8816585

Answer (score 11):

[$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) may also be useful, it solved one of my issues and can be used like this

```js
async mounted() {
  await this.$nextTick()
  // Code that will run only after the entire view has been rendered
}
```