# Vue.js devtools doesn't catch an emit in mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

It seems that when I try to emit an event in mounted it doesn't get triggered! therefore It doesnt show up in devtools

**main.js**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    mounted() {
        console.log('asd');
        this.$emit("clicked", "someValue");

    }
});
```

--

```
<body>

    <div id="app">

       <h1>vuejs</h1>

    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>   

</body>
```

Why is that? and how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

It works fine - your `console.log` outputs as it should, and you're emitting the event without issues.

In the code you've shown, though, you haven't set anything up to **listen** to the emitted event... Here's a simple, contrived example of how to do that with `this.$on`:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    mounted() {
        console.log('asd');

        this.$on('clicked', function(value) {
            alert('clicked!' + value);
        });

        this.$emit("clicked", "someValue");
    }
});
```

Demonstration: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKeWxJ

Comment: thanks, it worked. But why is the event is now showing in devtools?

Answer (score 1):

> When you add an event handler in the parent's mounted lifecycle event
>   for an event that is emitted in a child's mounted event, the handler
>   will not catch the event emitted by the child because the handler is
>   added after the child has already emitted the event. Basically the
>   cycle of events is like this.
>
> Parent's create Child's create Child's mounted Parent's mounted
>   Obviously there are other lifecycle events that occur, but that's the
>   sequence that matters in this case.
>
> If you want to handle an event emitted in the child, you need to
>   create the handler (call $on) before the child's mounted event.

[Is it possible to emit from mounted in Vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318643/is-it-possible-to-emit-from-mounted-in-vuejs)

Comment: This is good general info (have an upvote), but OP's example doesn't have any parent/child communication happening at all.