# Vue.js: Is there a way to know when the component instance is mounted?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a boolean we can access in each component instance to know when a component is mounted?

Something like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-if="$mounted">I am mounted</span>
    <span v-if="$created">I am created</span>
    <span>Called before created and mounted</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Sure. Use the `mounted` and `created` and `beforeCreate` functions natively supplied to you. Have a look at the [vue life-cycle diagram](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**UPDATE 2020**

There is an undocumented feature of Vue.js where you can know when a component's lifecycle hook is executed: [Source](https://dev.to/rolanddoda/8-secrets-vue-developers-must-know-5la#how-to-know-if-a-child-component-is-mounted-).

**The syntax is as follows:**

```html
<ChildComponent @hook:lifecycleHookName="callAMethod" />
```

**Examples:**

*How to know when a child component is mounted:*

```html
<ChildComponent @hook:mounted="componentMountedDoSomething" />
```

*How to know when a child component is created:*

```html
<ChildComponent @hook:created="componentCreatedDoSomething" />
```

---

---

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-if="mounted">I am mounted</span>
    <span v-if="created">I am created</span>
    <span>Called before created and mounted</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the script:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    created: false,
    mounted: false
  }),
  created () {
    this.created = true
  },
  mounted() {
    this.mounted = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was thinking. I was hoping Vue had a public boolean I could use to avoid these lines. :)

Comment: Well it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Bc of the code above I am not understanding what you are trying to do. But there are not many lines there IMO.

Comment: There is but since it's not in the official docs it might not be the best way to rely on it. But if you examine the `VueInstance` object you'll find `_isMounted`, `_isBeingDestroyed`etc. booleans. `created` would be implicitly by the fact that there even is a vue instance available.

Comment: How can one use this in JS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes use lifecycle hooks.

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  },
  created() {
    // `this` points to the vm instance
    console.log('a is: ' + this.a)
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("i am mounted in dom");
  }
})
```