# Nuxt fetch nested components knowing when they finished

Tags: nuxt.js

In page component I have fetch and I have fetch in my nested components, is there a way to know when all components finished their fetch in order to show loader, for now
I'm emit in every component isInitialized and make my page component v-show false until I get all the emits I did

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer yesterday but forgot to ping you back. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but maybe `$fetchState.pending` at the top is able to detect that every nested component is done fetching.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/

---

EDIT on the comments.
`this.$children` may work fine if you put it on a button `@click`. Meanwhile, if you plan to use it somewhere else, like in a lifecycle hook it starts to be a bit more tricky.

This is how this works (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319825/8816585):

1. Parent's create
2. Child's create
3. Child's mounted
4. Parent's mounted

Using [`@hook:mounted`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535239/8816585) can also be helpful if you plan to use the `mounted()` lifecycle.

TL;DR: those kind of things are pretty tricky to handle as you can see.

Comment: but if my nested components in v-else they aren't rendered, so the fetch wont happen until the fetch of the current component happen

Comment: The children need the parent fetch to be done before starting to fetch?

Comment: Otherwise, you could get the list of children from your parent components and check children's fetch state.

Comment: Yes the children need the parent fetch to be done, how I check children's fetch state with ref?

Comment: You can go to your vue devtools, click on a component and then in your console, look for 
`$vm0.$children`, this will list all of your components. If you select a specific component with something like `$vm0.$children[13].$fetchState.pending`, you'll be able to see if it does have a ended `fetch()` hook or not. So, for your issue, you could list all the children of your parent, see if it does have a `fetch()` hook, if it does, check if it's done. Some recursivity should be able to help too. Alternative solution, would be to have your data fetched globally and track it this way, far easier.

Comment: Ty sound good solution, and by globally you mean with store?

Comment: With the store, exactly: having some global state fetched and passed as props to all the children. Not sure if it's the best approach but this works.

Comment: ty last question how i get $vm0.$children in vue? this.$children isn't the same