# Vuetify styles being added after initial DOM load

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm on `"nuxt": "2.15.4"`, `"@nuxtjs/vuetify": "1.12.1"` and `"sass": "1.32.13"` and have a navbar component added to my default layout that uses `v-navigation-drawer` and at first moment of page load there is a flicker and every thing (drawer) splashed on screen and after that css is loaded.
I have read [nuxt-css-issue](https://github.com/kevinmarrec/nuxt-css-issue) this and kinda understand that it's because of nuxt and vuetify behaviour . so is there any way to solve this?? It's really ugly when you load the app !!

oh btw I use nuxt universal ssr and for vuetify treeShake is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you either wait for the CSS to come with the JS (better performance-wise, but may have some small flickering) or load all the CSS globally at the beginning, then the JS (less good in terms of speed, but no flicker). Do I understand the issue well?

Not sure if there is a real solution to this issue besides maybe display-hiding the component until he is loaded with a `@hook:mounted` hook and a `v-show` who is showing the component when done. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535239/8816585

Did you found out something on Vuetify's [github issues](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+loading+css)?
Not sure if there is something available yet, feel free to maybe post a new issue.

---

PS: there is maybe some shenanigan move here, to preload some CSS once we have reached a specific page or some hook. Not sure how would this be doable but knowing the JS ecosystem, this kind of hack may be feasable.

Comment: the css is for vuetify package , i didn't add anything manually so i don't know if it's added globally or not ; but the vuetify added globally itself. the problem is with my topnav which is added to default layout , so basically it's the first thing loaded.
As the main problem is with a side menu witch is bind to a data via `v-model` , I used `v-if` to don't show at all until the value for side menu is true.
And about github, already posted an issue on nuxt/vuetify

Comment: Sorry if I can't help more. Yeah, this is also an issue, understanding what is happening behind the curtains. Nice for Github!

Comment: actually `v-if` solved my problem. I was refactoring my codes by replacing vuetify components with my pure html/css codes; but now if that takes too much times, i'll use your trick with mounted hook and v-show