# Nuxt 2.14: wait until everything inside `fetch` will be done

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a question. Inside Nuxt's `fetch` hook I have some asynchronous calls that are performed by [Nuxt content](https://content.nuxtjs.org) API. [image]

Some pieces of this data are then used inside `mounted` hook.

[image]

But while Nuxt handles first request inside `fetch`, the control flow passes to the `mounted` hook and hence there's no needed data.

[image]

Yes, I tried uses something like `if (!this.$fetchState.pending) return;` but obviously `mounted` is called only once. Does anybody knows how can I force Nuxt to wait? Btw, the app is using static site generation and the component has property `fetchOnServer` set to false.

Comment: Did you tried using `asyncData` rather than `fetch`? This is blocking the transition until everything is done fetching. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#async-data

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a page component. This logic is inside `default.vue` layout file

Comment: So, you need to know that something is both `mounted` + `done fetching`, then run some code? You could use the `@hook` approach explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535239/8816585 Or make your call into a middleware that is called there. Since a middleware will wait for the query to be done before making the transition, it can achieve a blocking fetch hook. Otherwise, the best approach would be probably to find a different way of doing things like router guards (before/after navigation maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for future reference (by myself): in your `fetch` function you can set an instance variable to a promise that will be resolved once the remote call is complete, and then await that variable in `mounted`.

```
        export default {
            name: 'Search',
            data () {
                    const core = useCore();             
                    var data = {
                            source: null,
                            fetching: false,
                    };
                    return data;
            },
            fetch: async function(){
var self = this;
                    this.fetching = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
                            try{
                                    var req = await self.$axios.get("https://example.com/source.json");
                                    self.source = req.data;
                                    resolve();
                            }catch(err){
                                    console.log("Exception loading remote source: ", err);
                            }
                    });
        },
        fetchOnServer: false,       
            mounted: async function()
            {
                    if(this.fetching) await this.fetching;
            }
    }
```

Comment: The formatting tho. 