# How to check if child component is mounted in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, emit

I want to check if child component is mounted and I want to move that information to he parent component. For this I am using emits.
So with example here is my parent component:

```
<child @is-child-mounted="childMounted" />

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      childMounted: false,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    if (this.childMounted) {
      //do something
    }
  },
}
```

and in child component, I am changing 'is-child-mounted' to true:

```
mounted() {
    this.$emit('isChildMounted', true);
  },
```

But still **if (this.childMounted)** comes false. So how can I check in parent component if the child component is mounted?

Comment: `<child @is-child-mounted="childMounted = true" />` is enough. How would it be `false`, not really feasible. Interesting links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319825/8816585 and that one too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535239/8816585

Comment: mounted code only runs once (at mount time).  and parent and child mounted code does not run at the same time.  move the `if (this.childMounted)` code in your parent to a [method](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#methods)

Comment: Okay I moved it to method: isChildReady() {
      if (this.childMounted) {
       //do something
      }
    }, and then in mounted I called this function: this.isChildReady() but still comes false

Comment: Please update your question rather + be more explicit regarding "comes wrong". My comment doesn't work for you? Do you see something in your Vue devtools regarding the emit?

Comment: I tried to find supporting evidence in the documentation, but a member of the Vue core team did once outline in a forum thread the order of components mounting: [child mounted() runs first, then parent mounted()](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/order-of-lifecycle-hooks-for-parent-and-child/6681).  so there's not a real need to check for it.  if you are in the parent mounted hook, you can be guaranteed that the child has already mounted at that point.

Comment: A parent `mounted` executes after all child `mounted` have executed. Therefore, you don't need anything on the child component. All you need is to execute the code you want executed *"when the child has mounted"* inside the parent's `mounted`. See [this comment](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/order-of-lifecycle-hooks-for-parent-and-child/6681) of LinusBorg, or [this post](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f).

Comment: If `this.childMounted` is still false in parent `mounted` it means you have a typo somewhere and your emit is not actually working. But it is guaranteed the child has mounted. If you need more help please provide a *runnable* [mcve] and explain in clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a listener on the child component fom the parent. It would look like this:

```html
Vue3
      <Component
        @vnodeMounted="handleMounted"
      />
```

```html
Vue2
      <Component
         @hook:mounted="handleMounted"
      />
```

You can replace the hook name by the lifecycle one you want to listen to ! I guess it should be used sparsely as it is not present in the documentation and thus be an internal API that is not destined to be used directly.

source:

- https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4345#issuecomment-899082892
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/8d3fce029f20a73d5d0b1ff10cbf6fa73c989e62/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js#L348

Comment: This is certainly redundant for the reasons explained in comments, a child is guaranteed to be mounted when a parent is mounted, at least when there's no suspense. But the references are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in the event name in the child component while triggering  the event else code should work fine.

- It should be `is-child-mounted` instead of `ischildmounted`
- It should be `@is-child-mounted="childMounted = true"` instead of `@is-child-mounted="childMounted"`

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<p>{{ childmsg }}</p>',
  mounted() {
        this.$emit('is-child-mounted')
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
        childMounted: false
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.childMounted) {
      console.log('child mounted');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child childmsg="This is a child component" @is-child-mounted="childMounted = true"></child>
</div>
```