# vue/nuxt-How can I ensure the value from template is obtained first and passed to the child element?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get width value from Template and
pass the value to child component in vue/nuxt.

However, it doesn't work out. I assume that is because width from template is obtained later stage in life cycle hook.

How could I ensure the width value is obtained first and the child element gets the information?

**Parent**

```html
<template>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="4" ref="demandContainer">
    <div class="chart-container p-4 dark-background">
      <div class="font-weight-bold">Demand</div>
      <area-chart
        v-if="trendsData.length > 0"
        :data="trendsData"
        :baseWidth="width"
      >
      </area-chart>
    </div>
  </v-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  updated() {
    this.width = this.$refs.demandContainer.$el.clientWidth
  },
}
</script>
```

**Child**

```html
<svg ref="svg-area" :width="baseWidth" :height="baseHeight">
</svg>
```

**Error Message**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for the `$refs` to work you should make sure the template is fully rendered to the `DOM` and to do this you can have this code in the `mounted` hook:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => { this.width = this.$refs.demandContainer.$el.clientWidth; });
}
```

according to vue doc for `$nextTick`:

> vm.$nextTick( [callback] ): Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update. This is the same as the global Vue.nextTick, except that the callback’s this context is automatically bound to the instance calling this method.

so with the help of `$nextTick` you can make sure the element is rendered to `DOM` to use the `ref` defined on the element.

****Edit****

actually it is `$el` thats `undefined`. `this.$refs.demandContainer` returns the element itself and to get the width you can just have `this.$refs.demandContainer.clientWidth`.

check the example below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.demandContainer.clientWidth);
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="4" ref="demandContainer">
          <div class="chart-container p-4 dark-background">
            <div class="font-weight-bold">Demand</div>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Even after I put that in $nextTick, it doesn't allow me to access to the $refs and keeps saying the ref is not defined. why is that?

Comment: neither of them are working. The problem is it's not just vue application, rather it's nuxt application.

Comment: sorry, I can't think of anything else that might help!

Answer (score 0):

[Refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) are available only once the component is `mounted` to the actual DOM.
In created, it is created somewhere but not yet appended to your page.

The issue as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319825/8816585) is that you may have some issues to pass it to the child component since child's `mounted` lifecycle hook will happen **before** the parent's one.

I've tried some super hacky things

```js
async mounted() {
  await this.$nextTick()
  this.$watch(
    () => {
      return this.$refs.test.$el.clientWidth
    },
    (val) => {
      console.log('nice', val)
    },
  )
},
```

It did not work because `clientWidth` would be available at an even later point (lifecycle-wise). So, the last solution is probably to use some even more ugly `setTimeout`.

---

Or you could fix the issue with CSS, it will be:

- faster
- less heavy on the webpage
- more adapted
- less error prone

Because SVG are meant to be super responsive and easy to work with.
Can you show us what you want to do with your SVG?

TLDR: don't use JavaScript to solve a responsive issue here. Having to work with `parent` + `child` + `mounted` lifecycles is not a good idea usually.