# vuejs3 youtube-plugin YT is not defined console error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

When I detect a specific width via class binding to make a mobile responsive web and swap between templates using `display:none`, the console keeps giving me an error.
I'm having trouble using 2 YouTube templates. If you use only one YouTube, the error disappears.

> Error type: ReferenceError: YT is not defined. YouTube.vue?6574:118:25

If replacing the class binding template I used is a problem, is there another way?

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div
      class="youtube_container"
      :class="{'youtube_container on' : WidthActive}">
      <h3 class="youtube_title">
        desktop video
      </h3>
    <!-- add -->
    <component 
       is="script" 
       id="youtube-iframe-js-api-script"
       src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"
       />
      <YouTube
        src="https://youtu.be/GQmO52f26Ws"
        width="540" 
        height="360" />
    </div>
    <div
      class="youtube_container_mobile"
      :class="{'youtube_container_mobile on' : WidthmobileActive}">
      <h3 class="youtube_title">
        mobile video
      </h3>
      <YouTube
        src="https://youtu.be/GQmO52f26Ws"
        width="280" 
        height="300" 
        class="youtube_padding" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import YouTube from 'vue3-youtube'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const WidthActive = ref(true)
const WidthPostion  = ref(0)
//mobile
const WidthmobileActive = ref(false)
const WidthmobilePostion  = ref(0)

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  WidthmobileActive.value = WidthmobilePostion.value > 590
  WidthmobilePostion.value = window.innerWidth
})
 window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    WidthActive.value = WidthPostion.value < 591
    WidthPostion.value = window.innerWidth
})
</script>

<style>
.youtube_container{
  display: grid;
}
.youtube_container.on{
  display: none;
}
.youtube_container_mobile{
  display: grid;
}
.youtube_container_mobile.on{
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What is the line where you get that error? There is no `YT` in your code.

Comment: A problem occurs when two YouTube templates are used

Comment: You could bind props and make them change depending on screen size. I see that the only differences are classes, width and height. Then you would only use one Youtube component.

Comment: The first part of my answer is still the main one to try tbh. The 2nd one (with the refs) was more of a longshot.

Comment: I'm stuck on this issue.. @kissu

Comment: Did you tried the first approach with `<component ...`?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the first method. Are you saying to add that code directly above the <youtube>template? An error occurred when adding.

Comment: ReferenceError: YT is not defined
    at Proxy.initPlayer (YouTube.vue?6574:118:25) same error

Comment: Adding `<component>` once should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

Reversing `ref(false)` and `ref(true)` solved the issue.

---

This is a known issue apparently, maybe give a try to [that one](https://github.com/NomNes/vue3-youtube/issues/5#issuecomment-1220984121)

```html
<component 
  is="script" 
  id="youtube-iframe-js-api-script"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"
/>
```

Above your `<YouTube>` component.

---

Or maybe try to give it 2 differents refs aka `ref="youtube"` and `ref="youtube2"`, not sure.

---

Otherwise, add the following to an apex file

```html
<script id="youtube-iframe-js-api-script" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Comment: It's pretty unreadable in the comment section. Please update your question with a proper indentation + highlight (as I did for your question). @bxeom

Comment: I edited and uploaded it. It seems that my method is wrong. I'm not sure where it went wrong. :(

Comment: The problem is gone, but when the loading youtube brings up the second youtube and touches the width, it returns to normal..

Comment: @bxeom mainly comes from the fact of how you mount it to your DOM and the lifecycle of the component. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55328457/8816585) before resizing the whole thing.

Comment: Reversing ref(false) and ref(true) solved all the problems. thank you!

Comment: @bxeom your issue is solved? I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes i found the problem and solved it