Question about vue 3 lifecycle and availability of properties
I want to load some content of a vue component based on a given argument. Here is some code to illustrate:
ParentComponent.vue
<Suspense>
<div class="row g-0">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ChildComponent json-url="some/url/to/json/data" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ChildComponent json-url="some/url/to/json/data" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ChildComponent json-url="some/url/to/json/data" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ChildComponent json-url="some/url/to/json/data" />
  </div>
</div>

<template #fallback>
  <p>Loading...</p>
</template>

ChildComponent.vue
<template>
 <!-- some content based on the loaded json data -->
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted} from 'vue';
  

  defineProps({jsonUrl: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  }})
  const images = ref(null);
  const thumbnail = ref(null);
  const title = ref("");
  const description = ref("");

  onMounted(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(new URL(jsonUrl, import.meta.url).href);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      var jsonData = await response.json();

      images = jsonData["images"];
      thumbnail = jsonData["thumbnail"];
      title = jsonData["title"];
      description = jsonData["description"];
      console.log(thumbnail);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching the JSON file:', error);
    }
  });

</script>

The problem is that jsonUrl does not seem to be available during the onMounted() callback. Naming and everything should work, since if I simply put <p>{{json}}</p> into the template it shows the urls correctly.
I have searched around a bit, but it seems the property should be available? For example, this post answer shows pretty much the same approach (only difference being the usage of typescript).
How can I correctly load and initialize my content based on the json data within my child component here?

Probably because of this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319825/8816585

@kissu thanks for the link. This seems plausible, let me check. In the meanwhile, is there another callback function I can/should use for this kind of usecase?

Could maybe use Suspense to fine a fine-grain managment of the flow of your calls: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#suspense I don't remember all the ways to solve this issue but there are a few.

And yes - simple console.log() shows that children are called before the parents.

As said, use suspense for this and move async code to setup body. thumbnail = - this is a mistake, you lose reactivity by reassigning refs. "jsonUrl does not seem to be available" - how did you check? "new URL(jsonUrl, import.meta.url)" - this looks suspicious as you seem to try to fetch something from src/ , this is not how it works

When using setup, you have to define the props variable:
const props = defineProps({jsonUrl: {
  type: String,
  default: ""
}})

Then use props.jsonUrl to access the prop. This should allow you to access the prop inside of onMounted

Sorry, but my code already contains defineProps, so the issue lies elsewhere (according to the comments above most likely lifecycle stuff)

I meant you don't set the props to a variable in your code, you only have to add the const props =  part before the defineProps(...

Ah ok, in any case it doesn't really make a difference. While I can't find it in the docs atm, I have read somewhere that this shouldn't be needed and is assigned automatically. But thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Actually, I was wrong. As pointed out your actual answer using props.jsonUrl  works immediately. So your approach works (combined with the fact pointed out by the comments above, that I can simply put everything into an async setup body). Now I am just curious what happens behind the scenes with the properties and if this might lead to some issues down the line?

What do you exactly mean with "what happens behind the scenes"? Maybe I could explain a bit

Well defineProps() somehow initializes the properties, they are available sometime later in the lifecycle without assigning anything to props beforehand. I was just wondering how exactly this initialization works. In any case I don't suppose I am breaking anything, since I am only reading from the value, not assigning anything.

SFC's (single file components) are compiled into working javascript. defineProps is a compiler macro (therefore does not have to be imported) which tells the compiler to define the props.
It will be compiled into something like the following (simplified):
{
  props: ['jsonUrl'],
  setup(props) {
    // Rest of your component code
  }
}

As you can see, the rest of your code will be put into the setup method, which will immediately have access to the props variable.

perfect, thank you for the info!
