# How to create an Array inside firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Which code do I need to create an Array in `Firebase Firestore`?

I want to store `userDetails`:

```
  userName: this.userProfile.name,
  userImage: this.userProfile.image,
  userId: this.userProfile.userId
```

as an Array inside `Firestore`

`Vue` component:

```
...
data () {
 return {
     postDetails: {
      createdOn: new Date(),
      content: '',
      userId: null,
      image: null,
      comments: 0,
      likes: 0,
      userDetails: []
    }
    userData: [
     { userName: this.userProfile.name },
     { userImage: this.userProfile.image},
     { userId: this.userProfile.userId }
 }
},
methods: {
  createPost () {
    fb.postsCollection.add({
      createdOn: this.postDetails.createdOn,
      content: this.postDetails.content,
      userId: this.currentUser.uid,
      image: this.postDetails.image,
      comments: this.postDetails.comments,
      likes: this.postDetails.likes
      userData: this.userData
    }).then(ref => {
      this.post.content = ''
      this.$router.push('/dashboard')
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
```

[image: End result should look likes this one]

Comment: You already have two arrays in your document: tags and userData.  It's not clear at all to me what problem you're running into.

Comment: yes, but I added the both manually inside the firebase console

Comment: I have no idea how I can do this with code

Comment: Have you tried actually putting a JavaScript array populated with some data into your code?

Comment: Yes but in firestore it output its like a normal string

Comment: What part of your code is actually adding a populated array?  I don't see it.  I just see an empty array.

Comment: I updated the code, please take a look

Comment: The updated code should create an array called `userData` in the firebase Collection but I get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are adapting the code from this Firestore and Vue.js tutorial: https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase.

Actually in this tutorial the `userProfile` data is coming from the vue-store with

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['userProfile', 'currentUser', 'posts'])
  },
```

This part of the code is missing in your question but it is most probably the cause of your problem: In your Vue.js component, you try to use computed properties in data  but this is not possible "because of component creation timing: data evaluates **before** computed properties".

See [Use computed property in data in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318343/use-computed-property-in-data-in-vuejs) and https://forum.vuejs.org/t/computed-properties-in-data/11231

Just access directly the computed properties as follows, and it will work: `userData` will be stored as an array.

```
methods: {
  createPost () {
    fb.postsCollection.add({
      createdOn: this.postDetails.createdOn,
      content: this.postDetails.content,
      userId: this.currentUser.uid,
      image: this.postDetails.image,
      comments: this.postDetails.comments,
      likes: this.postDetails.likes
      userData: [
        { userName: this.userProfile.name },
        { userImage: this.userProfile.image},
        { userId: this.userProfile.userId }
      ]
    }).then(ref => {
      this.post.content = ''
      this.$router.push('/dashboard')
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but why is this not working: ´ userData: [
            { userName: this.userProfile.name,
              userImage: this.userProfile.image,
              userId: this.currentUser.userId
            }
          ]´

Comment: I want all 3 in index 0

Comment: Depending on where you are in the tutorial the value of `userImage` and `name` may be undefined. Try with only `userId: this.currentUser.userId`

Comment: I found the mistake, it won't work with the `currentUser´, only with userProfile

Comment: So everything is ok?