# Vue - use computed property inside HTML data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I use the return value of a computed property inside a data element that is rendered as HTML?

I have a data element that is HTML, and it looks like this:

```js
contractContent: `<p>Hi ${this.brideName},</p>`
```

I've also tried this:

```js
contractContent: `<p>Hi {{this.brideName}},</p>`
```

I am trying to pass in the name via this computed property:

```js
brideName() {
  return this.returnContracts[0].brideName.split(' ')[0]
},
```

But all I'm getting is `undefined`. If I just put `brideName` on the component as a test, it returns the first name of the bride just fine.

Where did I go astray?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4efaL3n/3/) with my dilemma

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use computed property in data in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318343/use-computed-property-in-data-in-vuejs)

Comment: @Tibebes.M no.. my problem is rendering the computed method inside of the HTML that's stored in data..

Comment: i've added an example you can check it out if that's what you want along with a fiddle

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the OP to show everyone what's going on

Comment: @ToddT Any particular reason for not using the template directly instead of through a computed prop? There's also JSX support in Vue CLI generated projects, which can be helpful in generating elements.

Comment: @tony19 yep, so this HTML is provided directly to vue-quill-editor. So I don't have a chance to render it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data()` is invoked on component creation and is not reactive. `contractContent` should be a computed prop for your code to work:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "Martina Navratilova",
    }
  },
  computed: {
    brideName() {
      return `<p>Hi ${this.name.split(' ')[0]},</p>`
    },
    contractContent() {
      return `<p>Hi there ${this.brideName}</p>`
    },
  },
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld/Ldbnosw4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going with data -> computed -> data -> render,
go directly with computed -> render (html)

In your template you can render html like this

```js
 <span v-html="brideName" />
```

assuming your data structure of `returnContracts` to be like this

```js
data: {
  returnContracts: [
    {
      "brideName": "Emma Watson"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can directly render brideName from computed

```js
brideName(){
  // assuming you'll have correct data, if data isn't valid this will cause crash.
  return `<p>Hi ${this.returnContracts[0].brideName.split(' ')[0]},</p>`
}
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxvb86d9/1/) to help you out implementation

Comment: shoot.. I updated your fiddle with what I'm trying to do! https://jsfiddle.net/v4efaL3n/3/

Comment: Accepted ans isn't good by performace presepctive if you get value and do operation in single function it's faster. also computed is just like data, if any data value used in computed is changed it will re-render it. 
https://jsfiddle.net/tsfv4ohk/